# WAF Not Blocking Hitleap

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I've tried every possible Filter for blocking hitleap and the fake traffic is still getting through:

```
 Header 'user-agent' contains: "HitLeap" after removing whitespace characters.

 Header 'user-agent' contains: "hitleap" after converting to lowercase.

 Header 'user-agent' matches exactly to: "HitLeap Viewer 2.8".

 Header 'user-agent' contains: "HitLeap".
```

I just don't get it because the User Agent is quite clearly "HitLeap Viewer 2.8"

I've assigned all the rules properly and added it to my cloudfront distribution. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you describe how your rules are set up in your WAF? Is your rule set to "Count requests" instead of Block by mistake? Is the rule actually associated with the web ACL? Making the rule isn't enough by itself, it needs to be associated with the web ACL.

Comment: Filter->Condition->Rule (Block Requests)->ACL->Cloudfront

Comment: If you spoof the header using `curl`, does the ACL block *that*?  It seems like your first step is to determine whether you can deliberately craft traffic to hit your own filter.

Comment: do you have a rule matching the request and configured to allow before the block?